# Eslint throws warning on missing return type for getter

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have a class:

```
export class Page {
   get page() {
      return $('#page');
   }

   open(path: string): void {
      browser.url(path);
      this.page.waitForDisplayed();
   }
}
```

Eslint throws warning:  `warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types` for getter `get page(){...}`.
I also have other classes like:

```
import { Page } from 'src/pages/page';

class ProductDetailPage extends Page {
  get skuLabel() {
    return $('#product_reference span');
  }
}

export const productDetailPage = new ProductDetailPage();
```

And for this getter `get skuLabel(){...}` eslint doesn't throw any warnings.

Does anybody has an idea why it throws a warning only in the first case?
Thanks!

Comment: Is `$` jQuery??

Comment: @CertainPerformance it is related to the automation framework I'm using - webdriverIO6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.4.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-module-boundary-types.md) only checks for explicit types on **exported** functions and classes' public methods.

In the first example, you are exporting the `Page` class, whereas in the second you are instead exporting an *instance* of `ProductDetailPage`. As you are not directly exporting the `ProductDetailPage` class, it is not considered to be exported by the rule and therefore missing parameter and return types won't be picked up on.

Comment: is there any way to force the rule to check it on ProductDetailPage? I would like to have the check there with the current setup.

Comment: You could use [`explicit-function-return-type`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.4.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md) (which is what I use), but you need to annotate the return type of every function, including non-exported ones. You can also configure it to ignore function expressions, typed function expressions, higher order functions, and more.